# Android: does FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK has effect within the same process?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, task

Suppose an application already has a stack of activities, and then a new activity is started from the application context with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. And this happens within the same process, i.e. inside the application, like this:

```
AppContext -> A(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) -> B -> C; AppContext -> D(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

According to the documentation we have 2 tasks now:

```
Task 1: A, B, C; Task 2: D
```

It follows from the doc that it is theoretically possible for the user to switch either to activity C or to activity D independently, as they belong to different tasks. In practice, however, I wasn't able to switch to activity C - it always switched to D.

**My question is:** 
Is it true that, if started in the same process with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, tasks are not independent and the user can only switch to the topmost activity in the topmost task?

**If the answer is "no"** then what is the way for the user to switch to task 1?

---

### **UPDATE**

The answer is: **No**
The tasks *are* independent and the user *can* switch between their activities independently, effectively having two activities of your app on the top of the stack. I just found the use case, three years after asking the original question.

Our app registers itself as a handler for a URL scheme (like `market://xxx.yyy/zzz`). Now let's imagine the user started the app with the launcher, got into a middle of something (activities `A, B, C`), and left off. Then in the browser the user clicks on a URL so our other activity is launched (activity `D`). This results in having two tasks in the same time: activities `A, B, C` (with `C` on top) and activity `D`. **The user can switch between these two activities via task history.**

Funny that Activity C is visible in the task history with the app's own icon but the Activity D is visible with the browser's icon. Regardless, both can be switched to.

Also, both tasks `A-B-C` and `D` run in the same process. This means that all singletone objects and static data are shared between them. As a result, they may corrupt each other's state if caution is not taken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a while after I've asked this question when I came across this link which I find very useful. It describes all flags and combinations very clear.

http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/

Comment: Kumar, the art of software development is, like any art, not copying others' code but getting inspired by it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to switch Tasks (versus Applications) exposed to the user. You can switch to the other task in code by starting the appropriate Activity.

**Edit** - [notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/index.html) are probably the best way to have the user switch tasks for which there are no launchers.

Answer (score 0):

I created a reference project to address this exact use-case:

https://github.com/theelfismike/android-parallel-paths